# NSNumber and intValue: weird behavior

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I'm a noob with Obj-C, but today I'm experiencing something I really can't understand on my own with NSNumber and intValue.

I have this example code:

```
    double quota = 203/100.0;    
    NSLog(@"%f %f %@ %d",
    quota,
    quota*100.0,
    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(quota*100.0)],
    [ [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(quota*100.0)] intValue]
);
```

which prints the output:

```
2.030000 203.000000 203 202
```

Please can someone help me to understand why the final intValue turns the 203 in 202?
I feel like I'm missing something really obvious and important.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

I ran your code and the result of 203/100.0 = 2.0299999999999998 while stored as a double. It looks like `NSNumber` as well as %f is rounding it to 2.03 when printing it but when you get the int value for 202.99999999999998 the .99999999999998 is being dropped. Hopefully someone (or my self with an edit) can add to why this rounding behavior is occurring when printing the double value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joe, it seems really strange to me this because I'd expect the intValue returning the nearest int value. After all the apple reference tells me the return value is "The receiver’s value as an int, converting it as necessary". I hope someone can clarify this concept.

Comment: Well generally a direct int value conversion will just drop all digits following the . and if you would like a rounded value you will need to explicitly call a Math rounding function. I am more interested why printing the values causes it round to 203